# Understanding char cast

Tags: java, casting, char

Im not understanding casting in java, char casting in particural. I'm not able to predict the outcome of this code,since I don't understand what the casting of char will "reproduce".Some explanation would be great! Thanks

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    int u = 10;

        double v = 22.105;

        byte w = 100;

        char x = 'a';

        float y = 20.5f;

        short z = 50;

        double d_Value = (float) ((char) (u/v) + y);

        Out.print(d_Value);

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is an integer-based data type, so you'd lose the precision from the double result on u/v, giving you a `0` number (or the `\0` char). Then it adds 20.5F for the final result: `20.5`.

Casting is a higher precedence than most operators in the language, so that cast is relevant before the `+` operation.

Comment: So after the u/v and the char cast what is the value of the u/v division? 0?

Comment: Before the cast, it's `(int) u / (double) v`, resulting in a `double` (since the two mismatched data types get promoted to double). So the value at that point is `0.45238...`, but by casting it to `char` (akin to casting to `int`) that number becomes `0`.

Comment: Oh okay, so basically char behaves like if you would cast it into an int? Thank you!

Comment: Java has a table for operator precedence in their tutorials, but I haven't found the official/JLS source for casting precedence yet. Along with array subscript (`[ index ]`) and member access (`.`), casting (`(type)`) is of a higher precedence than any arithmetic operator, and is evaluated before them. The only reason `u/v`  gets evaluated first is because it's a parenthesis enclosed expression

Comment: And correct, they're similar but `char` has a smaller maximum size; if you have a bigger number to deal with you have to start to worry about overflow